# How to replace for loop with list comprehension/map

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

Inside a function I have written I have:

```
keepList = [0]
add = 0
for j in range(1,(2*n)):
    if j%2 == 0:
        add += 1
    keepList.append((j*n+add))
```

where `n` is defined earlier in the function. This can be pretty slow as `n` becomes large (which it can when I call said function). How might I be able to use map or list comprehension to replace this so it does not slow my function down?

Comment: note that there is nothing magical about a map or list comprehension inherently that will give you amazing speedups over normal loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted, don't expect much performance boosts (if any) from using list comprehensions or `map`. However, using numpy will help. A loop really isn't necessary as everything can be calculated and vectorized:

```
def fn(n):
    arr = np.arange(2 * n)
    arr_add = np.repeat(np.arange(n), 2)
    return arr * n + arr_add
```

Comment: I should've known that numpy was the place to look. Thanks for the insight!